# How to clear formula in an excel cell if it is not empty

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am setting up an excel sheet to collect historical value assigned for a user, called "Dan" and I would like to save all values assigned to user against the appropriate data

**Link to spreadsheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zl8CJxh2dXtnxtVnpXhQOTb0XeBMT8EBhVjV_m9COxs/edit?usp=sharing

The spread sheet has two tabs

1. RAW - I will be pasting the raw user data here (example added)
2. History. This will save the values assigned to user

Eg : 1. On 20141123 (Nov 23rd), the value assigned to user(Dan) is 5(This will be at tab RAW). So I need to mark 5 against cell 20141123

During next day process, I have to clear all data from tab RAW and pasting the next day data

2. Next day 20141124, the value will be different say, 10. So I have to keep the old value against  20141123 and 10 again 20141124.

I did tried using below logic

1. Picking the value against specific date using a VLOOKUP
2. Added a ISBLANK to verify the next day. During the first day, "History" might added value against that day and if I paste new data next day, VLOOKUP will clear previous date data. so using a ISLOOKUP to keep that data, but it is not working as expected.

Can somebody give me an idea how can implement here
note: there will be 100 of users, here I gave only a single user details

Comment: how are the other users organized? you put them under one another in RAW? are the user names fixed? do they vary? is the date row in History fixed? how many dates do you have? OR is it all arbitrary? meaning that should you look up all the data in RAW and list them in History both names and dates? what formula do you use to pull up your value from RAW?

Comment: @AHC :         Yes.. All users will come in RAW one under another and these names are fixed. Dates in history will also be fixed. saving data of 25 days.I have to look for only dates in RAW. users names will be fixed in history as well

Comment: @AHC:          Updated the formula in the sheet. Currently added VLOOKUP, but if I change the date in RAW, the history tab data is getting clearing

Comment: Do you have only one use per day? if not, they you should define a condition to look up that particular user's corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a macro to copy and paste VALUES only in your history sheet.

```
Sub pastevalues()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

ws.Range("B3:F3").Copy

ws.Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

so you should run this macro each time to copy and paste values to your range in **history**.
you can keep a copy of your formula in the column after the last one or one before the first one, to apply it to the cells next day.